# How to use setInterval to repeat ajax calls from the ajax page itself?

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval, intervals, ajax-request

I have saved this as an ajax.js file:

```
function sendAjax(type, str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtResp").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtResp").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }


switch(type)
{
case 'search':
    xmlhttp.open('GET','mysql_process_search.php?q='+str,true); 
  break;
case 'add':
    xmlhttp.open("GET","mysql_process_event.php?q="+str,true); 
  break;
}

xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Basically, I am trying to use the built in setInterval() function to repeat whatever the URL variables contain.

In a sense, I need this to execute every 5 seconds after he tfunction sendAjax(type,str) is called (as in writ):

```
case 'add':
    xmlhttp.open("GET","mysql_process_event.php?q="+str,true); 
  break;
}

xmlhttp.send();
```

I could just set where I write the function on an interval: I.E.

```
setInterval( "sendAjax('message', '123')", 5000 );
sendAjax('message','123')
```

But I have several, several places throughout my code where this function is writ and this wont work if it is contained within an key action and if statement because it will only execute once:

```
$('#searchbar').live('keyup',function() {
    eInput = $(this).val();
    if (eInput.length > 1) {
    setInterval( "sendAjax('message', '123')", 5000 );
    sendAjax('message','123')
}
});
```

//This function doesn't work.

If someone can help me fix the last function, or just to include the setInterval within the Ajax.js file itself, I would greatly appreciate it.

Regards,
Taylor

Comment: emmm why dont you use jQuery's ajax methods if you are using jQuery? it would make ur life (and everyone else's lives) much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite that `function sendAjax(type, str)` much easier with jQuery (since thats what it seems you are using:

```
function sendAjax(type, str, succ){  //where succ is the success callback

   if (str=="")
   {
        $("#txtResp").empty();
        return;
   }

   if(succ === undefined) {   succ = null;  }

   switch(type)
   {
   case 'search':
       $.ajax({type:"GET",
               url: "mysql_process_search.php",
               data: "q="+str,
               success: succ
       }); 
     break;
   case 'add':
       $.ajax({type:"GET",
               url: "mysql_process_event.php",
               data: "q="+str,
               success: succ
       }); 
     break;
   }

}
```

Then do:

```
$('#searchbar').live('keyup',function() {
    eInput = $(this).val();
    if (eInput.length > 1) {
       sendAjax('message','123', function(responseText){
             $("#txtResp").html(responseText);
             setInterval( function(){
                     sendAjax('message', '123', function(responseText){
                            $("#txtResp").html(responseText);
                     })
              }, 5000 );
       })
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to specify your callback function

Comment: @RMorrisey, the OP does not have to

Comment: The original code has: document.getElementById("txtResp").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; It seems like this code is excluded from your answer, unless I'm misunderstanding something. +1 for using $.ajax, though

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I know to use jquery for making ajax calls now. I always assumed using the XMLHTTPRequest was preferred but this works great.